# ant how do I disable pre-dexing r21+

Tags: android, ant, dex

hello my ant build takes forever with pre-dexing after updating to r21

`[dex] Pre-Dexing myproject/android/google-play-services_lib/bin/classes.jar -> classes-27fa775977cf84dcd4ef76d9015649a6.jar`

This more than doubles my compile time. Pre-dexing would speed things up if I was only predexing once, but I'm actually reconfiguring my project several times for different ant builds, many times. So they all pre-dex , it is very annoying.

is there a flag I can enable in my ant script?

I've looked at an ant-maven github project but see no way of turning this off, I'm not 100% sure that project is related though.

help?

Comment: Yeah, pitty the pre-dexing has a bug or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From build.xml , it looks like you can change the property out.dex.input.absolute.dir for all different builds to point to a single directory outside target directory. If the pre-dexed file is present, i guess build system will not try to pre-dex it again.

```
out.dex.input.absolute.dir
```

Using [maven android plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) ], the post [here](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/161) indicates that predex is turned off by default , though the post is a day old, so maybe you need to get the latest beta version of plugin. You can disable predex by using

```
    <dexPreDex>false</dexPreDex>
```

Comment: everytime I update the android tools it overwrites these changes! aaagh where does that line go, dexPreDex?

Comment: @nandeesh You mean we should add <dexPreDex>false</dexPreDex>  to build.xml?  I tried that but in phonegap 3.3 it gives me error as that command is not recognized...

Comment: @AlexStanese His remark was in reference to the maven android plugin, not build.xml